# How do return values work?

Tags: python, return

```
def fudz(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    print("nom" * n)
    return fudz(n-1) + fudz(n//2)

result = fudz(4)
```

Can someone give me a step by step of this function?

Comment: Have a look into *recursion*.

Comment: It's a recursive function if that helps at all ;-).

Comment: Nope, but when you are going through it and have specific questions - we can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive function, which means it calls an instance of itself on a simplified instance of the problem until it gets to a base case for which it already knows the answer. Remember that any call to a function occurs in its own stack frame, so it's going to have its own value for n.

You can walk through it yourself. First, think about what happens when `n==2`. Then think about `n==3`, and increase `n` until it makes sense to you.